# Download attribute in anchor tag in React component

Tags: html, reactjs

I store files in the cloud so during the upload process they get prefixes that make their names unique. For example, if I upload a file named `test.txt`, during upload it gets saved as `7ea205f01ae5_test.txt`. It's important to note that I do capture and save the original file name.

In my React component, I'm trying to make it user friendly by using the download attribute so that when the user clicks to download the file, it'll be downloaded as `test.txt` but it's not working. The file still gets downloaded as `7ea205f01ae5_test.txt`.

This is what my React code looks like

```
<a href={fileUrl} download={origName}>{fileName}</a>
```

The object that my component looks like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  fileName: "7ea205f01ae5_test.txt",
  origName: "test.txt",
  fileUrl: "https://myBlobStorageUrl.com/container/7ea205f01ae5_test.txt?signature=123abcxyz"
}
```

Please note that the fileUrl contains a security access signature which allows user to access the file. Without it, user won't be given access to the file.

What do I need to do so that the file will be downloaded as `test.txt`?

Comment: This is an issue with react. Download attribute apparently doesn't work with cross origin links.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by DroidNoob this isn't particular to React. 
Any cross origin links will download with the server given file name and extension, however the `download` attribute will work for same origin.

```
// Domain: example.org

// Downloads as 281c2df7dbce9284dca6059db944f8df.png
<a download="foo.txt" target="_blank" href="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/281c2df7dbce9284dca6059db944f8df?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">download</a>

// Downloads as foo.txt
<a download="foo.txt" target="_blank" href="http://example.org/assets/avatar.png">download</a>
```

Depending on your backend, you could possible set up a route that generically maps the original names to the actual files names. So the frontend links to your backend mapper, and it in turns grabs the file.