# onClick "save image as" in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to simulate `Save Image As` when the user clicks on an image.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079758/simulate-save-image-as) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265625/download-attribute-in-anchor-tag-in-react-component) thread but I couldn't find the answer.

I'm using CRA and the image is **not** on my server. Is there a way where I can achieve this?

Here is a Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/save-image-as-react-pm3ts?file=/src/App.js

```
 <a
    href="https://img.mipon.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/14094031/logo-cover-website.png"
    download
      >
        <img
          download
          alt="Mipon"
          style={{ width: "300px" }}
          onClick={() => console.log("should trigger save image as")}
          src="https://img.mipon.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/14094031/logo-cover-website.png"
        />
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The download attribute will not work as intended since Blink engine will block cross-origin `<a download>`. Checkout [Deprecations and removals in Chrome 65](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_a_download).

> To avoid what is essentially a user-mediated cross-origin information
>   leakage, Blink will now ignore the presence of the download attribute
>   on anchor elements with cross origin attributes. Note that this
>   applies to HTMLAnchorElement.download as well as to the element
>   itself.

You may try to draw the image to a canvas element and download its dataURL. But this approach will work only if the requested domain has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers that allow shared requests. Images without CORS approval will taint the canvas and you will encounter error `Tainted canvases may not be exported download image` when you try to use methods like `toDataURL()`. In that case, you can host the image with services like `Cloudinary` and the download with canvas approach will work.

Here is a function to download an image using canvas, you may use it in a onclick event handler:

```
function downloadImage(src) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';  // This tells the browser to request cross-origin access when trying to download the image data.
  // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Implementing_the_save_feature
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = () => {
    // create Canvas
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    // create a tag
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = 'download.png';
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    a.click();
  };
}
```

[image: Edit save-image-as-react]

Comment: this is perfect, it works for unsplash api, getting urls.regular from an image